# How to reduce the stock for specific order status in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, stock

I am managing my stock on WooCommerce.

I would like to reduce the stock when the order status changes to a specific status for example (pending) or other status.

So I used this code:

```
function manageStock ($order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $instance ) {
   if ($old_status === 'on-hold'){
      wc_reduce_stock_levels($order_id);
   }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'manageStock', 10, 4 );
```

But unfortunately does not work. Is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Stock is already reduced for **"on-hold"**, **"processing"** and **"completed"** order statuses, as you can see [for `wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels()` function source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.9.2/includes/wc-stock-functions.php#L86-L115), hooking the function to the following hooks:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
```

So don't use directly `wc_reduce_stock_levels()` and replace by `wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels()`.

But on WooCommerce **pending** order status the function `wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels()` is triggered **that increase back stock levels**, so we need to remove that behavior first.

Now **to allow stock reduction for "pending" order status**, add this code lines:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending', 'wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
});
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

> Note that `woocommerce_order_status_{$status_transition_to}` is a composite hook that can be used with any other custom order status.

So for any **custom order status** *(let say "shipped" for example)*, we will use:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_shipped', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: I think I cannot reduce the stock again because the order when it was being "processing" the stock is already reduced.
Therefore I cannot reduce the stock for a specific status.
What do you think.
@LoicTheAztec

Comment: there is not a solution to solve this problem @LoicTheAztec thanks.

Comment: @zakitutu My answer here just answers your initial question… It shows you how stock is reduced or increased depending on statuses. You can remove WooCommerce behaviors and replace it with yours, using remove_action and add_action

Comment: doesn't work for me. the problem is 'woocommerce_order_status_pending' doesn't hook into wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels function.  I even add an add_option to monitor if this works.